# Wordpress WP_Query call posts AND pages

Tags: wordpress, post

I have a feature slider set up that draws in posts that are tagged 'feature'

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'showposts' => 3,
  'tag'  => 'feature' ));
```

Is is possible to draw in posts AND pages?
I know you can draw pages with `'post_type'=>'page'` but can you mix the two?

Comment: Never mind.... `'post_type'=>'any'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@fivedigit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920371/fivedigit) Thanks but I went with this in the end:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('any'),
    'tag'  => 'feature'
));
```

Although your version may come in handy in the future!

Answer (score 14):

You can specify an array value for the `post_type` parameter, as such:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('post', 'page'),
    'tag'  => 'feature'
));
```

See this page for more info: [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters)

Comment: This answer is more accurate for this question because he's asking for how to get only posts and pages, not any post type. `post_type => array('any')` may not work as expected if you install any plugin that creates new post types.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having to edit older code that doesn't use an array passed into WP_Query, you can add `&post_type=any` to get posts and pages (and other content).  Unfortunately I don't see a way to get posts and pages (without other types) without using an array, since post_type would then require an array as the examples above show.  However, this should be good enough if you are searching for a particular category anyway.

Example (this from vSlider v4.1.2 where `&post_type=any` is added so that pages are included in the slider):

```
$recent = new WP_Query($randimg."cat=".$options['imgCat']."&showposts=".$options['slideNr']."&post_type=any");
```

Thanks to @fivedigit and @my-jonny-wood for the answers above that led me to figuring this out and fixing the slider on my site!