# Wordpress Loop for pages AND posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I know it's possible to have multiple *post* loops on the same page, what I'm trying to achieve is having a single loop that will grab all pages and posts and then display them in chronological order.

So far I've only been able to loop for one or the other using `WP_Query`, two separate loops isn't an option as I need to be able to sort the output by date.

Does anyone have any experience doing something similar? Any advice on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress WP\_Query call posts AND pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680615/wordpress-wp-query-call-posts-and-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => array('carmarket', 'bikemarket') // or 'post', 'page' etc whatever you want

);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query